# How to use a depth texture in webgl2

Tags: javascript, webgl, framebuffer, webgl2

When you only want the **color** part of the frame, you can store **depth** in a **render buffer**.
This works fine for me on both **webgl1** and **webgl2**.

When you also need to use the **depth** part you can't use a **render buffer**, you need to store it in a **texture**.
In **webgl1** you need to get an extension to support it.
This also works fine for me in **webgl1**.

```
    const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
    const depthTextureExtension = gl.getExtension('WEBGL_depth_texture');
    if (!depthTextureExtension) {
        alert('Depth textures not supported');
    }
```

This feature should be available by default in **webgl2**.
Yet when I replace the code above with this:

```
    const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl2');
```

My code fails to render and I can not find any explanation why.

```
    this.texture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.texture);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, width, height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);


    this.depth = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.depth);
    checkGLErrors(gl); // OK
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT, width, height, 0, gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, null);
    checkGLErrors(gl); // for webgl2: 1281 INVALID_VALUE
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);


    this.framebuffer = gl.createFramebuffer();
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, this.framebuffer);
    gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.texture, 0);
    gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.depth, 0);
```

Comment: You might find [this article](https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-render-to-texture.html) helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In WebGL2 `DEPTH_COMPONENT` is not a valid internal format. Use `DEPTH_COMPONENT16`, `DEPTH_COMPONENT24` or `DEPTH_COMPONENT32F`

Example [from here](https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-render-to-texture.html)

```
  const level = 0;
  const internalFormat = gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT24;
  const border = 0;
  const format = gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT;
  const type = gl.UNSIGNED_INT;
  const data = null;
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, level, internalFormat,
                targetTextureWidth, targetTextureHeight, border,
                format, type, data);
```

Comment: I'm fairly surprised to see this since none of the docs I seen so far mention that webgl2 does not support all of the same options as webgl1

Comment: Btw I actually follow a lot of your work, but I must have skipped some of your webgl2 posts, so I took the time to go through it